# Why can't this struct method add an element to a vector through a mutable reference?

Tags: vector, rust, reference, mutable

I have been trying to implement SHA256 as a practice, but I stumbled upon a behavior that I do not fully understand.

I start with a `Vec<u8>`, where I place the data to be hashed. Then, I pass a mutable reference to the hash function, where it adds the SHA2 padding. The problem is that when the push function is reached within the hash function, it does not add a thing.

I determined this behavior using the debugger, since the program does not crashes, just hangs in the `while`.

```
use std::fmt;
struct Sha256 {
    state: [u32; 8],
    k: [u32; 64]
}

impl fmt::Display for Sha256 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}{:x?}",
            self.state[0],self.state[1],self.state[2],self.state[3],
            self.state[4],self.state[5],self.state[6],self.state[7]
        )
    }
}

impl Sha256 {
    pub fn new() -> Sha256 {
        Sha256 {
            state: [
                0x6a09e667,
                0xbb67ae85,
                0x3c6ef372,
                0xa54ff53a,
                0x510e527f,
                0x9b05688c,
                0x1f83d9ab,
                0x5be0cd19
            ],
            k: [
                0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
                0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
                0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
                0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
                0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
                0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
                0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
                0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
            ]
        }
    }

    pub fn process_block(&mut self, data: &[u8]) {
        let mut w = [0u32; 64];
        for (i, &d) in data.iter().enumerate() {
            let byte = i % 4;
            let word = i / 4;
            w[word] |= (d as u32) << ((8*(3-byte)) as u32);
        }
        println!("{:?}", w);
        for i in 16..64 {
            let s0 = w[i-15].rotate_right(7) ^ w[i-15].rotate_right(18) ^ w[i-15].rotate_right(3);
            let s1 = w[i-2].rotate_right(17) ^ w[i-2].rotate_right(19) ^ w[i-2].rotate_right(10);
            w[i] = w[i-16].wrapping_add(s0).wrapping_add(w[i-7]).wrapping_add(s1);
        }
        let mut a = self.state[0];
        let mut b = self.state[1];
        let mut c = self.state[2];
        let mut d = self.state[3];
        let mut e = self.state[4];
        let mut f = self.state[5];
        let mut g = self.state[6];
        let mut h = self.state[7];

        for i in 0..64 {
            let s1 = e.rotate_right(6) ^ e.rotate_right(11) ^ e.rotate_right(25);
            let ch = (e & f) ^((!e) & g);
            let t1 = h.wrapping_add(s1).wrapping_add(ch).wrapping_add(self.k[i]).wrapping_add(w[i]);
            let s0 = a.rotate_right(2) ^ a.rotate_right(13) ^ a.rotate_right(22);
            let maj = (a & b)^(a & c)^(b & c);
            let t2 = s0.wrapping_add(maj);

            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = d.wrapping_add(t1);
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = t1.wrapping_add(t2);
        }
        
        self.state[0] = self.state[0].wrapping_add(a);
        self.state[1] = self.state[1].wrapping_add(b);
        self.state[2] = self.state[2].wrapping_add(c);
        self.state[3] = self.state[3].wrapping_add(d);
        self.state[4] = self.state[4].wrapping_add(e);
        self.state[5] = self.state[5].wrapping_add(f);
        self.state[6] = self.state[6].wrapping_add(g);
        self.state[7] = self.state[7].wrapping_add(h);

    }

    pub fn hash(&mut self, v: &mut Vec<u8>) {
        v.push(0x80);
        while (v.len()%64) < 56 {
            v.push(0x00);
        }
        let size = v.len() as u64;
        let mut s_idx = 0;
        while s_idx < 8 {
            let byte = ((size >> (8*(7-s_idx))) & 0xffu64 ) as u8;
            s_idx += 1;
            v.push(byte);
        }

        println!("{:?}", v);

        for i in 0..(v.len()/64) {
            self.process_block(&v[i*64..(i+1)*64]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut th = Sha256::new();
    let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
//  Sha256::hash(&mut th, &mut v); // This not work
    th.hash(&mut v); // Neither do this

    println!("{}", th);
}
```

If I create another function I am able to push data within the function, like this:

```
fn add_elem(v: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    v.push(10);
}

fn main() {
    let mut th = Sha256::new();
    let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
    add_elem(&mut v);
    th.hash(&mut v);

    println!("{}", th);
}
```

I don't know what I am missing here, because the reference is the same, but it works sometimes and others not.

I am using the Rust 1.59 stable version for Linux and Windows (tested in both systems).

Comment: Which `while`, exactly, hangs? The first one?

Comment: In the function hash, the first while, since it tries to add elements, but the vector does not add the bytes.

Comment: It seems to be a debugger error, since the vector does in fact grow, but it is not shown in there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a debugger error in this function, since the vector does in fact grow, but it cannot be seen by calling `p v` in the GDB console.